# Tableau: Multiple User filter

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard that shows employees sales for the previous year. I have created a user filter that allows user X to only see user X data by following the steps in here: https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/publish_userfilters_create.htm#dynamic

In some cases, the employees work in teams so user Y and User Z should be able to see each other's data.

My reference table now includes these columns with some dummy data:

```
Employee ID | Username | Name         | Team
------------------------------------------------
123         | JSmith   | John Smith   | John Smith  
456         | AApple   | Allen Apple  | Team A
789         | BGarmin  | Brian Garmin | Team A
```

My current calculate field is

```
USERNAME() = [Username]
```

This works for only showing user X data to user X. But how can I show Team's A data to only people in Team A while still showing user X data to only user X? I created the Team column hoping that I can use it in the calculated field but I'm not having any luck.

The list of employees is about 130 and I would really not prefer to create a separate dashboard for teams and individuals.

Answer (score 0):

Create a user calculation

```
[Person] = USERNAME() OR ISMEMBEROF("National Managers")
```

This calculation checks if a person is included in the Region (People) field, or if a person is included in the National Managers group. If so, it returns true. [User Functions](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_user.htm)

**ISMEMBEROF** - Returns true if the person currently using Tableau is a member of a group that matches the given string. If the person currently using Tableau is signed in, the group membership is determined by groups on Tableau Server or Tableau Online. If the person is not signed in, this function returns false.